# Unable to add coverlet nuget package(s) - Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nuget, coverlet

When I try to add `coverlet.msbuild` to my test project I get this error:

```
The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long.  C:\my_repo\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets
```

I do see changes to my csproj:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.props')" />

<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets'))" />

<Import Project="..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets')" />
```

But no changes to `packages.config`, so it looks like the nuget isn't actually installed.

I'm trying to add this to a .net 4.8 test project.

Any ideas to what may cause this?

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you that the error is coming from `C:\my_repo\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets`. So let's take a look at it. Since Coverlet is open source, I can link to its source: https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/1e74dd43824fc49e90622a3442133c2d9f4e8e01/src/coverlet.msbuild.tasks/coverlet.msbuild.targets (current master branch commit, using permalink just in case the file changes in the future)

Since the error talks about `System.Version`, we can search for it, and we find it near the top, on line 11. It's trying to parse two properties, `_CoverletSdkNETCoreSdkVersion` and `_CoverletSdkMinVersionWithDependencyTarget`. The first property is defined as `_CoverletSdkNETCoreSdkVersion>$(NETCoreSdkVersion)</_CoverletSdkNETCoreSdkVersion>`.

Therefore I conclude that the package author only intends to support SDK sytle projects, not ".NET Framework" (non-sdk) style projects. They just implemented it in a way that crashes their code in non-sdk style projects.

Note that you can still target the .NET Framework using an SDK style project. Create a ".NET" (new branding for .NET Core since .NET 5) test project, then edit the csproj and change `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>`.

I don't know why coverlet isn't in your packages.config, the package installation seems successful, it's only failing at build time, which does not happen until install is finished.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with SDK style project vs non SKD? The project I'm trying to add this to is .net 4.8 btw.

Comment: If your csproj has `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`, or one of the other two syntaxes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2022#reference-a-project-sdk), then it's SDK style. If it doesn't (and your csproj lists every .cs file individually), then it's not sdk style and the package doesn't support your project.

Comment: Than I think I'm in the not supported camp, I can't find the word sdk anywhere in my csproj file (as you would expect given my question).

Comment: Can I change the project to be SDK style?